# Finding string within pyodbc dataset not working

Tags: python-3.x

New to Python, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to get a dataset from SQL and then search from another list within that dataset but its not finding any results, here is the code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT LOWER(id) FROM Tenant')
for r in resources:
    if r in cursor:
        print("keep " + r)
    else:
        print("deleting " + r)
```

The list contain the following:

cursor:

```
[('faccd3e2-fc72-4b03-b59c-30c65027ba4f', ), ('3592ab99-24fe-43d2-93f4-7b0d89f7304e', ), ('d2e488c4-e2e8-4c61-8019-e4e14df47433', )]
```

resources:

```
['6369b65b-937f-42c6-a88c-fd7bea43cf48', 'f5881b77-9107-43f9-b9b7-e33f39056ed6', 'faccd3e2-fc72-4b03-b59c-30c65027ba4f', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

It should match on faccd3e2-fc72-4b03-b59c-30c65027ba4f but its not, any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor` is a list of tuple. Flatten that and then compare.

**Ex:**

```
cursor = set(i[0] for i in cursor) # -->{'faccd3e2-fc72-4b03-b59c-30c65027ba4f', 'd2e488c4-e2e8-4c61-8019-e4e14df47433', '3592ab99-24fe-43d2-93f4-7b0d89f7304e'}
for r in resources:
    if r in cursor:
        print("keep " + r)
    else:
        print("deleting " + r)
```